# What Linux utility can split a large file into a multi-file archive that can be opened on Windows?

Tags: software-rec, compression

I have a 6GB file which I need to transport on DVDs. I have a Linux system, while the recipient has a Windows system. Is there any way for me to make a multi-part archive to spread the file across two DVDs that can be opened by a Windows user?

Comment: I have gotten the split file created on Linux, but I am having difficulty recombining it on Windows. Since there is no longer any Linux aspect to the remainder of the problem, I have opened  a SU question for that: http://superuser.com/questions/240086/how-can-i-combine-two-files-on-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rar is the common utility for operations such as this, as it is available on both platforms.

However, another approach is to use `split`.

```
split -b 1024m -d somefile somefile.
```

Then use 7zip on the Windows machine to re-combine the files.

Rar has the advantage of being a little simpler, but requires that it be installed on both machines.
Split has the advantage of it being faster, as it doesn't have to put the data in an archive, but leaves it as is.

Comment: I have tried using split and 7-zip cannot recombine the files. It says "Cannot detect file as splitted files."

Comment: To recombine the files, just use `copy /b file1+file2+file3 recombined.zip`

Comment: Try doing `split -b 1024m -d somefile somefile.0` (this will make the files called 'file.001' instead of 'file.01'. 7zip can be picky on its recognizing the its a simple split and not an archive. The copy also works, I just never remember it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Make a [zip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) archive and split it with

```
zipsplit -n 4699996160 foo.zip
```

I believe recent versions of Windows have built-in support for zip archives. If the recipient's system is too old, it may have [Winzip](http://www.winzip.com/) or [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

If you have a single file, you can split it with [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split):

```
split -b 4589840k -d pieces- large_file.dat
```

On the Windows machine, on the command line (press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd`), assemble it with

```
copy pieces-aa + pieces-ab large_file.dat
```

Comment: Using copy first-part + second-part output gets a 50kb output file, not the original file.

Comment: @Macha: Odd. I suggest you ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) for help with the Windows part. Since the questions will be closely related, link them to each other. Alternatively, flag your question for moderator attention and request a migration to Super User.

Comment: Done. http://superuser.com/questions/240086/how-can-i-combine-two-files-on-windows